# Excel formula to extract text from mid

Tags: excel, string, excel-formula, formula, extract

Here, I am extracting middle name from text using below formula

```
=MID(I2, SEARCH("-",I2) + 1, SEARCH("-",I2,SEARCH("-",I2)+1) - SEARCH("-",I2) - 1)
```

So from name "Goapta-Saaririka-Aaasshok", I can pull the "Saaririka" but I have a problem if I have only first name and middle name and not last name. Above formula is not working to pull the middle name from  "Basrsaaggade-Aamimit"

Please assist as how can I pull Mid name even if there is no last name.

Answer (score 1):

Test for the number of dashes.  For data in column **A**:

```
=IF(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",""))=2,MID(A1, SEARCH("-",A1) + 1, SEARCH("-",A1,SEARCH("-",A1)+1) - SEARCH("-",A1) - 1),MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1,99))
```

[image]

If there are 2 dashes, take the middle string
if there is 1 dash, take the last string.

*(with **Excel 365** this can be made much shorter)*

Comment: Million thanks.. Its work.. appreciate your help...

Comment: @gausshaikh, if it has worked for you, consider to accept the answer by clicking the checkmark on the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

No need to test for the number of dashes.

Assuming your data starts in A1. Put this in B1: `=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",REPT(" ",255)),256,256))`

Drag down.

It replaces every dash with 255 spaces, then it chops 256 chars from 256 chars in which guarantees the inclusion of the second element, then it trims off the excess spaces.

If you wish to do this with a UDF in VBA instead you can split the string into an array using "-" as the delimeter and take the second element.